# Google Scripts: Javascript function window.open not working in certain cases

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working through Google Scripts.

I currently have a script where if you click on a box, it is supposed to open a new tab with a URL drawn from spreadsheets.

The script correctly extracts the right URL:

```
var url = mainObj[i].link;
```

The following script opens the correct URL.

```
arr[i].onclick = function open() {window.open("https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive", "_blank") };
```

So it appears that window.open works correctly if I hard-code the URL into my script. However, I am extracting data from spreadsheet so I'm iterating on this function using a for loop.

So, if I try to do this:

```
arr[i].onclick = function open() {window.open(mainObj[i].link, "_blank") };
```

or even

```
var url = mainObj[i].link;
arr[i].onclick = function open() {window.open(url, "_blank") };
```

... it gives me a 400 error for both cases. What is the difference?

EDIT: I thought it was because currently, the variable `url` doesn't have the double quotes, but when I did the following, the error still persists.

```
var url = '"' + mainObj[i].link + '"';
console.log(url);
arr[i].onclick = function open() {window.open(url, "_blank") };
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are in a loop, "i" index is not save when you set it inside a onclick function, you need to encapsulate it inside an anonymous function and pass "i" to this function

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        arr[i].onclick = function open() {window.open(mainObj[i].link, "_blank") };
   })(i);
}
```

You can see an example here, with the first funtion all the buttons get the same onclick, with the secodn is fixed:
https://jsfiddle.net/angelmarde/5gegt2o6/